# Override Back Button In Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have storyboard with these flow. I am using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to navigate to each navigation controller.

```
- Navigation Controller 1 --> View Controller Initial (Home) --> View Controller Target
- Navigation Controller 2 --> View Controller X --> View Controller Y --> View Controller Target
- Navigation Controller 3 --> View Controller M --> View Controller Target
```

From **View Controller Target** on each flow, I want to override its back button so it could back to **View Controller Initial (Home)** and release its object on memory.

Is there any possible way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **I want to override its back button so it could back to View Controller Initial**, U meant here rootController of the navigationC.?

Comment: Yep, I want to go to Navigation Controller 1 from View Controller Target on each flow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to replace your back button with custom Back BarButton with it selector.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(self.backToInitial(_:)))

func backToInitial(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

If you are running `swift 3.0` then `selector` syntax is like this.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(self.backToInitial(sender:)))
```

**Edit:** For `SWRevealViewController` try like this.

```
let revealController = self.revealViewController;
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitialViewController") as! InitialViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
revealController.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated:true)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! But is that okay with its object on stack memory?

Comment: Eh, it was not overriding its back button but create new bar buton item on the left right? It's okay, but still need effort to create its button to be look like "back button".

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :) that you can create using custom barbutton item .

Answer (score -1):

For backButton action in View Controller Target, use this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```